# Semantic Web Service repository

Tags: web-services, semantic-web, owl

Does anybody know a good, public and large Web Services repository in which Web Services are semantically described (e.g., using OWL-S) that I could use in order to test some of my work?
Thanks!

Comment: The same question has been asked and the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17395574/1875434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any large OWL-S repository, I dont think it has received much traction.  I good resource might just be asking on the [OWL-S API](http://on.cs.unibas.ch/owls-api/) list; folks on there might know some services, or be hosting their own, that you could use.

Comment: I already asked there, but it seems desolated. I thought the same, that  it has not received much traction. If you know any other repository please tell me, specially if the Web Service are described using semantic technologies, does not matter if they are not OWL-S

Comment: http://sswap.info/ uses a different take on semantic web services than the OWL-S approach.  It is under active development, though it's early in its life, so adoption is slim.  But it's worth investigating if you are looking into semantic web services.