# semantic web services search engine

Tags: web-services, search-engine, semantics, semantic-web

I am searching for a set of semantic web services to test my work.
Does anybody know a public web services search engine, or any web services repository in which web services are semantically described (e.g., using [OWL-S](http://www.w3.org/Submission/OWL-S/))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these resources

[OWL for Services (OWL-S) - Examples](http://www.ai.sri.com/daml/services/owl-s/examples.html)

[Collection of OWL-S Web Services](http://www.andreas-hess.info/projects/annotator/owl-ds.html)